# HashCode for conditional equals

Tags: java, data-structures, hash, hashcode

I would like to generate a hash-code for the following equals-method.

```
public MyClass class {

  private int a;
  private final String b;

  public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof MyClass)) return false;

        MyClass myClass = (MyClass) o;
        return a == myClass.a || (b == null ? myClass.b == null : b.equals(myClass.b));
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
      int result = (int) (a^ (a >>> 32));
      result = 31 * result + (b != null ? b.hashCode() : 0);
      return result;
  }

}
```

The catch is that equals returns true in a single or both of 2 cases: either o1.a == o2.a or o1.b == o2.b. In such a case usual hash won't be the same for: myClass("a", "b") and myClass("a", null)

Comment: Solution: Either use a compound key for hash data structures or a separate differenemt hash data structure for each field respectively.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Forget the hash - your equality comparison is fundamentally broken to start with.

Consider three values:

```
foo: a=10, b=0
bar: a=10, b=5
baz: a=20, b=5
```

Now:

```
foo.equals(bar) => true because of a
bar.equals(baz) => true because of b
foo.equals(baz) => false because neither a nor b match
```

This violates the transitivity requirements of [`Object.equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-):

> for any non-null reference values `x`, `y`, and `z`, if `x.equals(y)` returns `true` and `y.equals(z)` returns `true`, then `x.equals(z)` should return `true`.

If you don't have transitivity, it's going to be really hard to come up with a valid `hashCode` implementation other than returning a constant (which is valid, but not exactly useful).